# Echo a value from a JSON made with php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to echo value of a JSON with PHP. Actually, my JSON is mounted like the following

```
<?php 

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Voluntary simplified    
$json = '{';
$json .= '"10": "tomato",';
$json .= '"20": "cherry"';
$json .= '}';

echo $json;

?>
```

When I want to echo a value:

```
$json = file_get_contents('json.php');
$itemsArray = json_decode($json);

print_r($itemsArray);
```

But nothing are echoed. Is there a reason for that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Because `file_get_contents` __gets content of file__ and not file's output.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand like that. Use `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use return instead of echo in your json file, echo use for print data in the browser, not to return data.

```
<?php

$json = '{';
$json .= '"10": "tomato",';
$json .= '"20": "cherry"';
$json .= '}';

return $json;

?>
```

and in your main file, whatever you have name it, use include and assign to a variable.

```
<?php
$json = include 'json.php';
$itemsArray = json_decode($json);

var_dump($itemsArray);

?>
```

it will decode a json data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `header()` function in the include file will send that header to the client of the main PHP script. That's probably not what you want.